# How do I add a previous and next button to ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'am using visual studio 2010 and made windows application form for the one form I am using SQL server which shows the information of a table from the sql database.

When I click the next button it will go to the next row and if I click the previous it will go to previous rows?

And how do I get the data of the first colomn of a `ListView` and insert it to `Label1` when clicking next and previous button?

Comment: Please ask one question in each post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property `MultiSelect` in your listview to false, you'll be able to do this:

```
private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = listView1.SelectedIndices[0] - 1;

    // In case we're in the first row
    if (index < 0)
        return;

    listView1.Items[index].Selected = true;
}

private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = listView1.SelectedIndices[0] + 1;

    // In case we're in the last row
    if (index >= listView1.Items.Count)
        return;

    listView1.Items[index].Selected = true;
}
```

Setting the `Selected` property of an item de-selects the other items (if MultiSelect is set to false).

---

You could even go from the last row to the first row for example by setting the index to 0 or `listView1.Items.Count - 1`.

Comment: listView1.Items.Count - 1, How to set this if i go to last row and click that button i will go to first row??

Comment: After the `if (index >= listView1.Items.Count)` instead of returning, you would do `index = 0`. This way you'll go back to the first row.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your list view is set to select only 1 item `MultiSelect = false` then you can use:

```
int index = listView1.SelectedIndices[0] + 1;
listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();
listView1.SelectedIndices.Add(index);
```

to step forwards and

```
int index = listView1.SelectedIndices[0] - 1;
listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();
listView1.SelectedIndices.Add(index);
```

to step backwards.

NB: You will need to do some value checking to make sure that when you step back you don't go below 0 and when you step forward you don't go past the total number of items in the listview.

To get the contents of the current item you'll need an event attached to your listview `SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        ListViewItem currentitem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
        label1.Text = currentitem.Text;
    }
    else
        label1.Text = string.Empty;
}
```